# Class Orientated Objects in Python error?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been having some issues with my code, you see I am a beginner at python programming and so I don't understand all the errors, So I would be quite happy for assistance down below is the code, which I have checked intensively just to find the error:

```
class Animal(object):
def __init__(self,legs,name):
    def sleep(self,hours):
        print("%s is sleeping for %d hours!" % (self.name,hours))
    self.legs = legs
    self.name = name
roscoe = Animal(4, "Canis Lupus Familiaris")
roscoe.name = ("Roscoe")
roscoe.sleep(4)
```

This is the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "class.py", line 9, in <module>
roscoe.sleep(4)
AttributeError: 'Animal' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

Comment: roscOe vs roscUe, the error is correct the u version doesn't exist

Comment: check the proper syntax for creating a method within a class.

Comment: I did the new error is different

Comment: As the original question is edited with the answer, and now the OP is running into a new problem. I believe the OP should open a new question with the new problem, and roll back the edit to validate the correct answer given on the original question.

Comment: @Inferno :: do not edit your question with information from answers or comments. Now we have an answer for the original question, which was correct. But for new visitors to this question the answer is no longer valid, and only leads to confusion. Please rollback your edits, and post a new question for your new problem.

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error in the last line.
It should be:

```
roscoe.sleep(4)
```

instead of

```
roscue.sleep(4)
```

Giving more context since I see you're a begginner at Python. The traceback of Python interpreter (the "program" that runs Python code) tells you what happened. In this case, it says "name 'roscue' is not defined". This is usually a syntax error. Sometimes it can mean that you haven't defined that function. But in this case, it's the former.

Also, going a little bit further, you're probably going to get an error of indentation. In Python, you have to indent every block that you want to put together, either with tabs or with spaces.

Finally, think about your functions, you have to put them in order. Init is a function, and sleep is another function, so after each one you have a block. Different blocks should be indented separately. Here's how the code should look, but revise it instead of running it blindly.

```
class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self,legs,name):
    self.legs = legs
    self.name = name
  def sleep(self,hours):
    print("%s is sleeping for %d hours!" % (self.name,hours))

roscoe = Animal(4, "Canis Lupus Familiaris")
roscoe.name = ("Roscoe")
roscoe.sleep(4)
```

Comment: I've corrected the problem, however, now I get an attribute error

Comment: Look at the updated answer, your code was a little bit off. Make sure you understand what a block is and how you should define functions properly. Each function in the Animal class should be indented at the same level, and you don't want to nest functions like you did in your original post.

Comment: Another error this time I tried taking the parameters off but didn't work and thank you for helping out so far the main issue has been dealt with.

Comment: Just remember that if you take the parameters off the call, you have to take them off the function definition as well. For other problems, I suggest that you open a new question.

Comment: Currently I'm learning off of a python book called 'Python book for beginners' author is Charlie masterson the only problem is it teaches python 2.7.12 and I am using python 3 latest so syntax and some commands are different been running into so many errors.

Comment: There are tons of books and online tutorials for Python 3.  Perhaps you'd have better success with a different resource ..or run your code in Python 2.